# Is it possible to run multiple mappers on one node

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I have the code of KMeans and my task is to calculate the speedup, I've done it by running it on different numbers of nodes in my uni's clusters. But is it possible to change the number of mappers and/or reducers, so that I can check the change in speedup while running it on single node.

While googling, I found that by using `conf.setNumReduceTasks(2);` I can change the numbers of reducers. but I havn't see any change in my output. (My output is the time in ms).

The code I am using is from github: https://github.com/himank/K-Means/blob/master/src/KMeans.java
Although I've made some changes according to my requirement, but the main functionality is the same.

Here is how main function looks like:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    IN = args[0];
    OUT = args[1];
    String input = IN;
    String output = OUT + System.nanoTime();
    String again_input = output;
    int iteration = 0;
    boolean isdone = false;
    while (isdone == false) {
        JobConf conf = new JobConf(KMeans.class);
        if (iteration == 0) {
            Path hdfsPath = new Path(input + CENTROID_FILE_NAME);
            DistributedCache.addCacheFile(hdfsPath.toUri(), conf);
        } else {
            Path hdfsPath = new Path(again_input + OUTPUT_FILE_NAME);
            DistributedCache.addCacheFile(hdfsPath.toUri(), conf);
        }
        conf.setJobName(JOB_NAME);
        //conf.setNumReduceTasks(2);
        conf.setMapOutputKeyClass(DoubleWritable.class);
        conf.setMapOutputValueClass(DoubleWritable.class);
        conf.setOutputKeyClass(DoubleWritable.class);
        conf.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
        conf.setMapperClass(Map.class);
        conf.setNumMapTasks(4);
        conf.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);
        conf.setInputFormat(TextInputFormat.class);
        conf.setOutputFormat(TextOutputFormat.class);
        FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(conf, new Path(input + DATA_FILE_NAME));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf, new Path(output));
        JobClient.runJob(conf);
        Path ofile = new Path(output + OUTPUT_FILE_NAME);   

        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(new URI("hdfs://127.0.0.1:9000"), configuration);
        Path filePath = new Path(output + OUTPUT_FILE_NAME);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fs.open(filePath)));
        List<Double> centers_next = new ArrayList<Double>();
        String line = br.readLine();
        while (line != null) {
            String[] sp = line.split("\t| ");
            double c = Double.parseDouble(sp[0]);
            centers_next.add(c);
            line = br.readLine();
        }
        br.close();
        String prev;
        if (iteration == 0) {
            prev = input + CENTROID_FILE_NAME;
        } else {
            prev = again_input + OUTPUT_FILE_NAME;
        }
        Path prevfile = new Path(prev);
        FileSystem fs1 = FileSystem.get(new URI("hdfs://127.0.0.1:9000"), configuration);
        BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fs1.open(prevfile)));
        List<Double> centers_prev = new ArrayList<Double>();
        String l = br1.readLine();
        while (l != null) {
            String[] sp1 = l.split(SPLITTER);
            double d = Double.parseDouble(sp1[0]);
            centers_prev.add(d);
            l = br1.readLine();
        }
        br1.close();
        Collections.sort(centers_next);
        Collections.sort(centers_prev);
        Iterator<Double> it = centers_prev.iterator();
        for (double d : centers_next) {
            double temp = it.next();
            if (Math.abs(temp - d) <= 0.1) {
                isdone = true;
            } else {
                isdone = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        ++iteration;
        again_input = output;
        output = OUT + System.nanoTime();
    }
    long endTime   = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long totalTime = endTime - startTime;
    System.out.println(totalTime);
}
```

PS. I am new to Hadoop and MapReduce.

Comment: You probably should wait for the job to complete before reading the file from HDFS

Comment: @Ahsan: Are you looking for the performance tuning part of it and that's why you want to try setting number of mappers and reducers

Comment: @ramprasad-g yes as I said I am calculating speedup. I've got speedup by increasing the numbers of nodes. Now I want to calculate it on single node by increasing the number of mappers and reducers.

Comment: Normally Single node test has less resources available. Multi-node test with the same data volume and resources available would be better to count the speed. Would suggest to do multi-node test with optimizations (in this case number of mappers and reducers) one by one and count the performance . Moreover, there are several other factors (like sort memory etc...) which will/can improve performance of map-reduce program.

Comment: Also have a look at general tips added in my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of maps for a given job is usually driven by the number of input splits in the input files and not by the setNumMapTasks() or mapred.map.tasks parameter. a Map task is spawned for each input split. the mapred.map.tasks parameter is just a hint to the InputFormat for the number of maps. the number of map tasks can  be increased manually using setNumMapTasks(), It can be used to increase the number of map tasks, but will not set the number below that which Hadoop determines via splitting the input data.

http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/HowManyMapsAndReduces

Answer (score 1):

Apache [Map Reduce Tutorial](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/MapReduceTutorial.html) provides more info.

**How Many Maps?**

> The number of maps is usually driven by the total size of the inputs, that is, the total number of blocks of the input files.

***The right level of parallelism for maps seems to be around 10-100 maps per-node***, although it has been set up to 300 maps for very cpu-light map tasks. Task setup takes a while, so it is best if the maps take at least a minute to execute.

Thus, if you expect 10TB of input data and have a blocksize of 128MB, you’ll end up with 82,000 maps, unless `Configuration.set(MRJobConfig.NUM_MAPS, int)` (which only provides a hint to the framework) is used to set it even higher.

Comment: `The right level of parallelism for maps seems to be around 10-100 maps per-node` That is highly dependend on your hardware setup. What are you maxing out? Network bandwidth, disk bandwidth?