# Multiple rows insertion in HBase using MapReduce

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hbase

I want to insert N rows to HBase table from each mapper in batch. I am currenly aware of two ways of doing this:

1. Create a list of [Put](https://archive.cloudera.com/cdh5/cdh/5/hbase/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/Put.html) objects and use `put(List<Put> puts)` method of [HTable](https://hbase.apache.org/0.94/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/HTable.html) instance and also make sure to disable `autoFlush` parameter.
2. Use [TableOutputFormat](https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/mapreduce/TableOutputFormat.html) class and use `context.write(rowKey, put)` method.

Which one is better?

In 1st way, `context.write()` is not required since `hTable.put(putsList)` method is used to directly put data in table. My mapper class is extending `Class Mapper<KEYIN,VALUEIN,KEYOUT,VALUEOUT>`, so what classes should I use for `KEYOUT` and `VALUEOUT`?

In 2nd way, I have to call `context.write(rowKey, put)` N times. Is there any way by which I can use `context.write()` for list of `Put` operations?

Is there any other way of doing this with MapReduce?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why single mapper why not multiple mappers? how do you specify the number of mappers? even if you specify that is suggestion to code no guarantee that number of mappers will be one.

Comment: You can change number of mappers using setNumMapTasks or conf.set('mapred.map.tasks','numberofmappersyouwanttoset') (but its a suggestion to configuration ) but there is no guarantee that mapper instances will be set. Moreover, It depends on inputsplits.

Comment: lookat http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37239944/is-it-possible-to-run-multiple-mappers-on-one-node please see my elaborate answer.. feel free to ask questions.

Comment: also For using your 1st way can be done in like  "public class HBasePutOrDeleteMapper extends TableMapper<NullWritable, NullWritable>{"

Comment: I dont know where you got example. of  "My mapper class is extending Class Mapper<KEYIN,VALUEIN,KEYOUT,VALUEOUT>, so what classes should I use for KEYOUT and VALUEOUT"

Comment: your question is very broad and legthy(cane be ignored by users to answer)... I advise, cut short in to small questions  in future

Comment: Thanks @RamPrasad G for help. From single mapper I meant each mapper. I will correct my question.

Comment: For case 1, If nothing is being written to Output directory in MapReduce job, then `NullOutputFormat` class should be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I  prefer second option where batching is natural(no need for list of
>   puts) for mapreduce.... to have deep insight please see my second point

1) Your first option `List<Put>` is generally used for Standalone Hbase Java client. Internally it is controlled by `hbase.client.write.buffer` like below in one of your config xmls

```
<property>
         <name>hbase.client.write.buffer</name>
         <value>20971520</value> // around 2 mb i guess
 </property>
```

which has default value say 2mb size. once you buffer is filled then it will flush all puts to actually insert in to your table. which is same way as BufferedMutator as explained in #2

2) Regarding second option, if you see [TableOutputFormat](https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/mapreduce/TableOutputFormat.html) documentation

```
org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce
Class TableOutputFormat<KEY>

java.lang.Object
org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.OutputFormat<KEY,Mutation>
org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableOutputFormat<KEY>
All Implemented Interfaces:
org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configurable

@InterfaceAudience.Public
@InterfaceStability.Stable
public class TableOutputFormat<KEY>
extends org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.OutputFormat<KEY,Mutation>
implements org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configurable
Convert Map/Reduce output and write it to an HBase table. The KEY is ignored
```

***[while the output value must be either a Put or a Delete instance](https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/mapreduce/TableOutputFormat.html).***

-- ***Other way of seeing this through [code](https://github.com/apache/hbase/blob/d7a4499dfc8b3936a0eca867589fc2b23b597866/hbase-server/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/mapreduce/TableOutputFormat.java) is like below.***

```
/**
     * Writes a key/value pair into the table.
     *
     * @param key  The key.
     * @param value  The value.
     * @throws IOException When writing fails.
     * @see RecordWriter#write(Object, Object)
     */
    @Override
    public void write(KEY key, Mutation value)
    throws IOException {
      if (!(value instanceof Put) && !(value instanceof Delete)) {
        throw new IOException("Pass a Delete or a Put");
      }
      mutator.mutate(value);
    }
  }
```

> conclusion : context.write(rowkey,putlist) It is not possible with API.

However, [BufferedMutator](https://github.com/apache/hbase/blob/a1f0c1cbb3b227c9a4369d4fee45dab52014177a/hbase-client/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/BufferedMutator.java) ( from mutator.mutate in above code) says

[Map/reduce jobs  benefit from batching, but have no natural flush point. {@code BufferedMutator} receives the  puts from the M/R job and will batch puts based on some heuristic, such as the accumulated size   of the puts, and submit batches of puts asynchronously so that the M/R logic can continue  without interruption.](https://github.com/apache/hbase/blob/a1f0c1cbb3b227c9a4369d4fee45dab52014177a/hbase-client/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/BufferedMutator.java)

> so your batching is natural(with BufferedMutator) as aforementioned